# This dependency was not found: * .components/table in ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib

Tags: vue.js, webpack, bootstrap-4, webpack-dev-server

Trying to add bootstrapVue to my project has scrambled my dependencies in my webpack Vuejs project. Everything was dandy until I tried to implement [this](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-management/#loading-css) npm install and subsequent change to "webpack.config.js". Immediately everything began to fall apart. The dev server couldn't compile for various reasons, so I did 'npm uninstall style-loader css-loader'. That didn't help. Eventually I came across a solution that involved removing my changes to the "webpack.config.js" file. Cool, now I could at least run my project again.

Somewhere along the line my node_modules/babel-loader/package.json file started giving me problems. Inside, the bundleDependencies: has a value of false. VS Code is telling me it should be an array of package names. Okay, I'm not sure how I can remedy this warning, so I ignore it.

I added a new .vue component to my src/components file named 'Table.vue' to use within my main App.vue. Added my `import Table from ".components/table";` line to my App.vue file. Now my dev server fails to compile for this reason: [terminal error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpskx.jpg).

In this project, I've already installed: axios, vue-axios, sass-loader, node-sass, webpack, bootstrap, bootstrap-vue. I'm pretty new to all of this so any help would be greatly appreciated. Worst case scenario I just start from scratch and copy paste my code.

Comment: try `./components/table`

Comment: My goodness, programming in a nutshell. I guess I conflated my immediate problem with the hairy mess of the past. This works, thanks.